# Выводится только фон (pygame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

#Окно и название окна
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 700))
pygame.display.set_caption('"Pug Racing" by Said')

#Изображения
Jumping = pygame.image.load('Pug_2.png')
Standing = pygame.image.load('Pug_1.png')
bg = pygame.image.load('фон.jpg')

#Кадры
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Расположение мопса
x = 300
y = 315

#Характеристики мопса
widht = 128
heidht = 128
speed = 10

#Характеристики прыжка
Jump = False
JumpCount = 10

#Покраска окна
def draw_window():
    win.blit(bg, (0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    if Jump:
        win.blit(Jumping, (x,y))

    else:
        win.blit(Standing, (x,y))

#Процесс игры
run_game = True
while run_game:
    #Обновление событий
    clock.tick(60)

    #Перебираем события
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run_game = False

    #Управление
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if not Jump:
        Stand = True
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            Stand = False
            Jump = True
    else:
        if JumpCount >= -10:
            if JumpCount < 0:
                y += (JumpCount **2) / 3
            else:
                y -= (JumpCount **2) / 3
            JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            Jump = False
            JumpCount = 10

    draw_window()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

#Окно и название окна
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption('"Pug Racing" by Said')

#Изображения
Jumping = pygame.image.load('Ok.png')
Standing = pygame.image.load('on.png')
bg = pygame.image.load('lena.jpg')

#Кадры
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Расположение мопса
x = 300
y = 315

#Характеристики мопса
widht = 128
heidht = 128
speed = 10

#Характеристики прыжка
Jump = False  # True 
JumpCount = 10

#Покраска окна
def draw_window():
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))

#    pygame.display.update()                        # ---
    if Jump:
        win.blit(Jumping, (x, y))
    else:
        win.blit(Standing, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()                         # +++

#Процесс игры
run_game = True
while run_game:
    #Обновление событий
    clock.tick(60)

    #Перебираем события
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run_game = False

    #Управление
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if not Jump:
        Stand = True
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            Stand = False
            Jump = True
    else:
        if JumpCount >= -10:
            if JumpCount < 0:
                y += (JumpCount **2) / 3
            else:
                y -= (JumpCount **2) / 3
            JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            Jump = False
            JumpCount = 10

    draw_window()

pygame.quit()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]